# Laravel - Insert en tres tablas relacionals con autoincrements

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Un saludo,

Actualmente tengo este modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario donde registro mi dominio, cuando registro mi dominio a la vez debo registrar las direcciones ip asociadas a ese dominio, pero necesito hacer el registro en las tres tablas en un solo llamado a la acción, teniendo en cuenta que los campos pk deben conservar ese id para ser registrados en la tabla relacional.

Un ejemplo del formuarlio seria el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde los datos del campo `Domain Name` irian para la tabla `domains` y las ipadress a la tabla `ipadress` y a su vez crear la relación en la tabla ipadress_domains.

Agradecería la ayuda que me puedan brindar para poder ejecutar ese registro en un solo llamado a la acción, supongo que debo tener el Model para cada una de las tablas y el registro ejecutar en un metodo en el controlador "x" pero desconozco de que forma hacerlo, solo he aprendido con Laravel a ejectura registros simples con `Class::create()`

Comment: Nos muestras que has intentado por favor?, Tienes los modelos y relaciones creados?

Comment: Solo tengo los modelos creados extendiendo la clase Model, no se como relacionar los modelos aun

Answer (score 0):

[![Verifica ese codigo con las relaciones de eloquent yo puede realizarlo][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QKqs.png cualquier cosa me avisas

Answer (score 0):

Bueno basicamente puedes usar eloquent en la consulta para guardar en diferentes tablas.

`````
````$domain = Domain::create([array de campos]);
    $domain->ipsDomains()->create([array de campos]);
      return $domain; ````
`````

En fin para una relación uno a muchos, para una muchos a muchos usas el método sync(array mix)

Comment: Convendría que ampliaras tu respuesta en razón de que el OP indica en comentarios o tener creadas las relaciones

Comment: Que hace el método ipsDomains?